# What is it that makes the rotation?

Tags: matlab

I have the following MatLab code. I would like to understand what is exactly that makes the variables to change where the figure (Triangle) is going to be plotted next?

here is the code

```
clf
X = [.1 .8 .9 .1];
Y = [.2 .1 .7 .2];

fill(X,Y,'g','edgecolor','k','linewidth',1), 
hold on
axis equal, axis([-1.2 1.2 -1.2 1.2]), pause(0.2)
v = pi/6; 
A = [cos(v) -sin(v); sin(v) cos(v)];
P = [X; Y];

for i = 1:13
  P = A * P;  
  fill(P(1,:),P(2,:),'g','edgecolor','r','linewidth',1), pause(0.2)
end
plot(0,0,'ko','linewidth',2,'markersize',2)  % origo
hold off
```

Comment: `P` is changing value with every loop iteration: `P = A * P`

Comment: How is that happning because all the determinants of P lie outside the loop. Theres nothing like p[i] @excaza

Comment: Loops are not in their own workspace. The `P` being modified in the loop is the same as the `P` outside of the loop. So the first iteration is `A*[X; Y]`, the second is `A*A*[X; Y]`, etc.

Comment: As a simpler illustration, consider this: `A = 0; for ii = 1:5; A = A + 1; end; disp(A)`

Comment: * is [matrix multiplication](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [cos(v) -sin(v); sin(v) cos(v)];
```

is a rotation matrix.

If you multiply `A * [x,y]`  you get an `[x,y]` that is rotated by `v` (radians).
The code then takes that new `[x,y]` and repeats the process.